# How to add an image to all frames of a GIF using Imagemagick?

Tags: image, imagemagick

I would like to create a lightning effect for a photo using a lightning stock image and a personal photo.  For example using the following lightning image:

[image]

I would like to put the panda below in all frames of the gif using Imagemagick:

[image]

I tried extracting all the frames using the command:

```
convert -coalesce lightning.gif out%05d.pgm
```

But I am stuck at how to do a batch `composite` operation for all frames.  Would anyone know how to achieve this?  I was hoping that there would be a single line solution using Imagemagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with `-coalesce` to separate the frames, I think the key ingredient in putting them back together is the **MIFF** (Magick Image File Format) which can be used to stream multiple images.

So, here I stream all the individual, composited frames from inside a `for` loop into the final `convert` outside the loop to put them all back together:

```
convert lightning.gif -coalesce frames-%03d.gif

for f in frame*gif; do
   convert $f -gravity south \( panda.jpg -resize 50% \) \
      -compose colordodge -composite miff:-
done | convert -delay 80 miff:-  anim.gif
```

[image]

The selection of a decent blending mode is another issue!

As a one-liner, that looks like this:

```
for f in frame*gif; do convert $f -gravity south \( panda.jpg -resize 50% \) -compose colordodge -composite miff:- ; done | convert -delay 80 miff:-  anim.gif
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, the solution looks great.  I can figure out the blending to get things neat.